# Google Maps like zooming

Tags: javascript, zooming, mousewheel

I'm trying to build a browser app that let's the user zoom in and out of a vector image using the scroll wheel.
However, right now when you scroll it just takes the displacement vector from the mouse to the center of the scrollable area and translates the image in the opposite direction.

```
function mousewheel(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    zoom.amount+=e.wheelDeltaY/300;
    if (zoom.amount<zoom.min) {zoom.amount=zoom.min;}
    else{
      zoom.x -= (e.layerX-(map.clientWidth/2));
      zoom.y -= (e.layerY-(map.clientHeight/2));
    }
    zoom.update();
}
```

http://aerracenmedia.github.io/AthiusInteractiveMap/app/index.html

Ideally I would like to make it so it continually zooms in on whatever your mouse is on (like google maps)
instead of just shifting the map.
How would I implement that?